# Calling API from a x86 DLL loaded into a x64 application

Tags: c++, assembly, winapi, x86-64, fasm

This is an experiment to exploit the availability of a 32-bit "compatibility" mode selector in GDT in Windows x64 which has the value of 0x23.

I 've successfully loaded a x86 DLL into the address space of a x64 application. This is done by first taking all imports of the x86 dll and saving it into a XML, then using a modified [MemoryModule](https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule) to load the DLL from memory and patch the Import Address Table with those pointers.

Then, in the x64 host I jump to a compatibility code segment:

```
push 0x23    
xor rcx,rcx    
mov ecx,Start32  
push rcx
retf
```

`Start32` is a 32-bit entry point that would call a configured function:

```
USE32
push eax
push dword [WhatToPass]
mov eax, [WhatToCall]
call eax
pop eax
```

Then go back to 64-bit

```
USE64
db 0eah
ret_64:
dd 0
dw 0x33
nop
```

This works, as long as the configured `exp1` function does practically nothing. The concept is fully discussed in my CodeProject [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5336312/Load-a-x86-DLL-into-a-x64-executable-mission-possi) and the source is on [GitHub](https://github.com/WindowsNT/Mission6432).

It doesn't work when run in Visual Studio, but it does work when run in WinDbg; WinDbg shows a 'x86' running mode when switching.

Now the ambitious project is to call the API from the x86 module. This fails even with a simple `MessageBeep(0);`. I don't of course expect it at this point to go fully to the function but it doesn't even enter; I get an invalid execution instruction on the call. The address is valid.

What could be wrong? Yes this is too much perhaps but I'm still curious.

Patching the IAT works correctly. Sample code:

```
void PatchIAT(HINSTANCE h,std::vector<FANDP>* CustomLoading = 0)
{
    PCHAR codeBase = (PCHAR)h;
    XML3::XML x(xResult);
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32           ntheaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)(PCHAR(h) + PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(h)->e_lfanew);
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER       pSech = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(ntheaders);//Pointer to first section header
    DWORD ulsize = 0;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR importDesc = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)ImageDirectoryEntryToData(h, TRUE, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT, &ulsize);
    if (!importDesc)
        return;

    for (; importDesc && importDesc->Name; importDesc++) {

        PSTR pszModName = (PSTR)((PBYTE)h + importDesc->Name);
        if (!pszModName)
            break;

        XML3::XMLElement* module = ... ; // find the XML entry
        if (!module)
            continue;

        DWORD* thunkRef;
        DWORD* funcRef = 0;

        if (importDesc->OriginalFirstThunk) {
            thunkRef = (DWORD*)(codeBase + importDesc->OriginalFirstThunk);
            funcRef = (DWORD*)(codeBase + importDesc->FirstThunk);
        }
        else {
            // no hint table
            thunkRef = (DWORD*)(codeBase + importDesc->FirstThunk);
            funcRef = (DWORD *)(codeBase + importDesc->FirstThunk);
        }

        DWORD V = 0;
        for (; *thunkRef; thunkRef++, funcRef++) {

            DWORD* wr = (DWORD*)funcRef;

            if (IMAGE_SNAP_BY_ORDINAL(*thunkRef)) {
//                *funcRef = module->getProcAddress(handle, (LPCSTR)IMAGE_ORDINAL(*thunkRef), module->userdata);

                const char* fe = (LPCSTR)IMAGE_ORDINAL(*thunkRef);
                 // find V from xml 
                ...

            }
            else {
                PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME thunkData = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)(codeBase + (*thunkRef));
//                *wr = module->getProcAddress(handle, (LPCSTR)&thunkData->Name, module->userdata);
             ... // Find V from XML
            }


            // Patch it now...
            DWORD dwOldProtect = 0;
            if (VirtualProtect((LPVOID)wr, 4, PAGE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect))
            {
                memcpy((void*)wr, &V, 4);
                VirtualProtect((LPVOID)wr, 4, dwOldProtect, &dwOldProtect);
            }
            VirtualProtect((LPVOID)V, 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwOldProtect);
        }

    }




}
```

Comment: I am curious why you want to do it like this. Seems pretty fragile to me. I personally would host the dll in a seperate 32 bit process and use RPC (e.g. gRPC) to interact with (presumably) legacy code.

Comment: I'd imagine that `MessageBeep` is the 64-bit version but you're in 32-bit mode

Comment: *"This works, as long as the configured `exp1` function does practically nothing."* - That's a pretty strong indication that you got the calling convention wrong. Leaf functions are fairly forgiving when they run off of a stack that's not properly aligned.

Comment: I suppose you already saw this http://blog.rewolf.pl/blog/?p=102 although if focuses more on calling x64 from x86, it should be quite similar. Otherwise if the need is to load plugins with a given interface and that interface is "reasonably remotable" (not sending gigabytes of data to each call), you could add a generic COM wrapper and use COM facility https://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/

Comment: @SimonMourier yes I 'm doing it this way. This is just for experiments.

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes, this is just an experiment. In production code I'm doing it with COM.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Haha phwew... ;)  I must say last time I did anything like this was in 16/32 bit era (386?) and that was pure assembly ;)

Comment: @IInspectable okay but would this prevent MessageBeep() from entering anyway?  I think that it's simply that the 32-bit stuff is not mapped to my address space.

Comment: In order to help we need a [mcve]. When you resolve the imports, are you loading the 32-bit DLLs or the 64-bit ones? How are you calling the imported functions? Is the injected 32-bit DLL written in C or in ASM? The syscall mechanism is different in WOW64 and your 32-bit DLL dependencies may call (eg: WOW32Reserved) onto DLLs (e.g. wow64.dll) that weren't loaded for a native proc. See [this](https://wbenny.github.io/2018/11/04/wow64-internals.html). Remember: 32-bit system DLLs are written assuming a WOW64 env. Windows 64-bit has not 32-bit syscall and you need to switch back to 64-bit and ...

Comment: ... marshal the arguments. This is what WOW64 does and what the system DLLs assume.